# How to add a failure callback for kafka-python kafka.KafkaProducer#send()?

Tags: kafka-python

I would like to set a callback to be fired if a produced records fail.  Initially, I would just like to log the failed record.

The Confluent Kafka python library provides a mechanism for adding a callback:

```
produce(topic[, value][, key][, partition][, on_delivery][, timestamp])
...
    on_delivery(err,msg) (func) – Delivery report callback to call (from poll() or flush()) on successful or failed delivery
```

How can I achieve similar behaviour with kafka-python [kafka.KafkaProducer#send()](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaProducer.html#kafka.KafkaProducer.send) without having to use the deprecated SimpleClient using  [kafka.SimpleClient#send_produce_request()](http://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/kafka.html#kafka.SimpleClient.send_produce_request)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although it isn't documented, this is relatively straightforward. Whenever you send a message, you immediately get a `Future` back. You can append callbacks/errback's to that `Future`:

```
F = producer.send(topic=topic, value=message, key=key)
F.add_callback(callback, message=message, **kwargs_to_pass_to_callback_method)
F.add_errback(erback, message=message, **kwargs_to_pass_to_errback_method)
```

Relevant source code here:
https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/blob/1937ce59b4706b44091bb536a9b810ae657c3225/kafka/future.py#L48-L64

We really should document this, I filed https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/issues/1256 to track it.